# spring security logout handler not working

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

i have grails pluggin spring-security-core-1.2.1

I registered security event listener as a spring bean in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
securityEventListener(LoggingSecurityEventListener)
```

and make two additions to grails-app/conf/Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames =
    ['rememberMeServices',
            'securityContextLogoutHandler',
            'securityEventListener']
```

my logging/logout listener

```
class LoggingSecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent>, LogoutHandler {

            void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
                System.out.println('appEvent')
            }


            void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) {
                System.out.println('logout')
            }

}
```

on ApplicationEvent works good, but logout not working
what could be the problem?

or you can tell how to get all logging users

Answer (score 4):

When you set

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

the spring security plugin will register it's own event listener called `securityEventListener`.  The handler looked up from `handlerNames` is probably getting the plugin registered one instead of yours.  Try renaming your bean to something like:

```
loggingSecurityEventListener(LoggingSecurityEventListener)
```

and replacing the `handlerNames` with

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = 
    ['rememberMeServices',
     'securityContextLogoutHandler',
     'loggingSecurityEventListener']
```

NOTE: the configuration property names have changed (`plugins` -> `plugin`).  If you're using the grails spring-security plugin version 2.0 or later, use this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames
```

Comment: Works for me with a fresh grails app.  Note that you'll only get logout events if the user explicitly clicks on a logout link (e.g. `http://<hostname>/<appname>/logout/`).