# Custom Logout Handler Not Working Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have implemented custom Logout handler in grails. For some reasons, it is not working. I have checked a similar question on stackoverflow 
[spring security logout handler not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900534/spring-security-logout-handler-not-working) ,but it did not work for me. The problem is my custom method is not being called.
My code is as follows:

`Config.groovy`

```
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/v1/login/**': 'authenticationProcessingFilter,restAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor,restExceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/api/v1/logout/**': 'authenticationProcessingFilter,restAuthenticationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,restLogoutFilter',
    '/**': 'securityContextPersistenceFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter,restAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor']

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames =
    ['rememberMeServices', 'myHandler' ,
     'securityEventListener',
     'securityContextLogoutHandler']
```

`resources.groovy`

```
    beans = {
myHandler(com.as.rest.handlers.CustomSecurityContextLogoutHandler) }
```

`CustomSecurityContextLogoutHandler.groovy`

```
    package com.as.rest.handlers

    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse


    class CustomSecurityContextLogoutHandler extends SecurityContextLogoutHandler {

@Override
void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) {

    println("#############################################")
    println("#############################################")
    println("#############################################")
    println("logout")
}

    }
```

Comment: might be related to logout.handlers: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/logoutHandlers.html grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = [
   'rememberMeServices', 'securityContextLogoutHandler', 'myLogoutHandler'
]

Comment: @vahid - I have registered my custom handler in the same way as given in the link provided by you.